# How can we say modals are of category T, but auxiliaries are really verbs?

Tags: syntax, english, auxiliary-verbs, modal-verbs

Are there any arguments or theories to account for it?

Comment: The question is difficult to understand. Does T stand for tense? I suggest adding some context to make the question more accessible.

Comment: In the anglocentric view of GG auxiliaries are Is, but generally they have their own category (Aux, say).

Comment: There's no reason why any of the tense-aspect-mood-evidentiality words/affixes couldn't have their own phrasal categories. Focusing only on tense phrases is surely a historical quirk (and probably because of bias from English being tense prominent.)

Comment: Related question: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17324/are-modal-verbs-lexical-or-grammatical-categories

Comment: And see this answer: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/27988/9781

Comment: What do you mean by 'category T'?